# Widevine Crashes In Youtube Precertification Tests

Tags: youtube, cobalt, widevine, eme

I am working with Cobalt for Youtube.

When passing EME Conformance tests, Widevine tests causes a crash on my Set Top Box

Do you have any idea what may be the reason for this crash?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: I got these traces : [ERROR:cdm/src/cdm.cpp(782):getKeyStatuses] No such session: ksid7A09AAF6
### 01:44:48.443 pid=2467 tid=0x89d7e450 MediaDrmContext(121): error in getting key statuses. result=102
Caught signal: SIGSEGV (11)
[ 6288.604264] *** 441034:58:38.80 nexus_demux: [ 6288.608492] NEXUS_SetPidChannelBypassKeyslot PidChannel c3b0d380 leak. Will only cleanup on client exit. 441034:58:37.97 nxserverlib: cobalt(0x9f1061a0) unregistered
Segmentation fault
# [ 6289.617753] *** 441034:58:39.81 nexus_surface_compositor: [ 6289.623105] auto_disable of unused graphics

Answer (score 1):

From your stack trace, there is no log related to cobalt and it indicates you are using Broadcom platform. It would be better to ask your Broadcom contact about this issue. It's highly possible that it is fixed in recent updates.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by `No such session` error, this could indicate a problem with your `SbDrm...()` implementation. Did you run NPLB tests? Try `ninja -C out/linux-x64x11_debug nplb` followed by `out/linux-x64x11_debug/nplb`. Replace `linux-x64x11` with the name of your platform.

For the reference, NPLB is a conformance test suite for Starboard, see https://cobalt.dev/starboard/testing.html.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Yes, I tried to run the NPLB tests and I have the test results too, no failure is related to SbDrm..

Answer (score 0):

after running "ninja -C out/linux-x64x11_debug nplb" libnplb.so file is generated what should I do next to run nplb tests.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35756568)